# Loop through multiple folder and extract tabular data into dataframe and save path into dataframe

Tags: python

1. I need to loop through multiple folders and find .pdf files inside each folder. The folder names need to be read & separated and saved as data frame under Column names = 'Category' , 'Brand', 'SKU' , 'Type', 'Test', 'Direction'.
2. From the pdf files I need to extract tables and in that I need to find maximum values and convert it into a single data frame.

Below is my code please help me how to proceed

```
        import glob
        from tabula import *
        import tabula
        import pandas as pd
        from pathlib import Path

    paths = Path("C:\\Users\\Inspiron\\Desktop\\A\\1\\Biscuits and Crackers").glob('**/*.pdf')
    for path in paths:
        path_in_str = str(path)
        print(path_in_str)
        file = path_in_str
        file_split = file.split("\\")
        file_split = file_split[6:12]
        print(file_split)

        df1=pd.DataFrame(data=file_split)
        df1_transpose = df1.transpose()
        print(df1_transpose)
        df2 = df1_transpose.rename(columns = 
        {0:'Category',1:'Brand',2:'SKU',3:'Type',4:'Test',5:'Direction'})
        print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
 0                        1      2       3    4   5
0  Biscuits and Crackers  Belvita Bites Chocolate  03332  Carton  ECT  CD

                Category                    Brand    SKU    Type Test  \
0  Biscuits and Crackers  Belvita Bites Chocolate  03332  Carton  ECT   

  Direction  
0        CD
```

I am getting as separate dataframe for each pdf file, but I need all pdf data into a single dataframe. Row numbers are zero for all and column names repeating. I tried to append list but couldnot do it.

I am also attaching screenshot of the expected output.

[image: Output expected]

Comment: in your question you have two different problems - (1) get all PDF in folder and subfolders, (2) get table from PDF. You should ask for one problem.

Comment: first learn how to format code in question - it has to be ``` three ticks (on left of key `1`, below `ESC`) , not `'''`

Comment: maybe first append all to one list and at the end convert this list to DataFrame. OR before loop create emtpy `DataFrame` and late use functions like `df.concat`, `df.merge`, `df.append` to append to this DataFrame`. At this moment in every loop you create new DataFrame and you assing to the same `df1` so you remove previous `DataFrame` and you lose it.

Comment: instead of `str(path)` and `file.split("\\")` try `path.parts`. ie. `file_split = path.parts[6:12]`